# rwd-theme how to move the language / currency bar

Tags: rwd-theme

I've managed to be able to hide the language/currency bar at the top of the screen by editing the header.phtml, however when I try to move for example the following code into the footer - it doesn't appear.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>
```

Am I missing something, or should I also be editing the template files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In directory.xml
Change:

```
<reference name="header">
     <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency_switcher" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

to:

```
<reference name="footer">
     <block type="directory/currency" name="currency" as="currency_switcher" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**EDIT:**

By Default Currency should show on footer, if you look at directory.xml line 39

```
<reference name="footer">
            <block type="directory/currency" name="footer_currency" after="footer_store_language" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

if it is not showing in footer so you need to add:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_currency') ?>
```

**Local.xml**

```
<reference name="footer">
<block type="directory/currency" name="footer-currency" template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to add it into the footer. Have I missed a step?

Comment: Did you add <?php echo getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?> to footer?

Comment: I added <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?> to the footer.

Comment: The location of the footer.phtml I edited was /template/page/html/footer.phtml

Comment: can you try  in footer <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_currency') ?>

Comment: That hasn't worked either unfortunately.

Comment: was it working on header before you made any changes?

Comment: Yes, it was working. No other changes have been made to any of the files.

Comment: see my edit please I did try it on clean Magento and it is working

Comment: No need to copy and modify xml files. Just create a local.xml and update from there.

Comment: @philwinkle  I do agree with you I did edit my post

Comment: @AhmedElAwadi That's worked perfectly - thank you very much for your time and patience. I had forgot about local.xml - I will use this instead.

Comment: @James thanks for thumb up, but if this is the correct answer you can mark it as correct